# Arango DB Filter query for print array of value

Tags: arangodb, aql

Given the following document structure:

```
{
"name": [
{
  "use": "official",
  "family": "Chalmers",
  "given": [
    "Peter",
    "James"
  ]
},
{
  "use": "usual",
  "given": [
    "Jim"
  ]
},
{
  "use": "maiden",
  "family": "Windsor",
  "given": [
    "Peter",
    "James"
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

**Query:**
`FOR client IN Patient FILTER    client.name[*].use=='official' RETURN client.name[*].given`

I have telecom and name array.
I want to query to compare if  name[*].use=='official' then print corresponding give array.

**Expected result:**
"given": [
"Peter",
"James"
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.name[*].use` is an array, so you need to use an array operator. It can be either of the following:

- `'string' in doc.attribute`
- `doc.attribute ANY == 'string'`
- `doc.attribute ANY IN ['string']`

To return just the given names from the 'official' array, you can use a subquery:

```
RETURN { given:
  FIRST(FOR name IN client.name FILTER name.use == 'official' LIMIT 1 RETURN name.given)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an [inline expression](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/advanced-array-operators.html#inline-expressions):

```
FOR client IN Patient
  FILTER 'official' IN client.name[*].use
  RETURN { given:
    FIRST(client.name[* FILTER CURRENT.use == 'official' LIMIT 1 RETURN CURRENT.given])
  }
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "given": [
      "Peter",
      "James"
    ]
  }
]
```

---

In your original post, the example document and query didn't match, but assuming the following structure:

```
{
  "telecom": [
    {
      "use": "official",
      "value": "+1 (03) 5555 6473 82"
    },
    {
      "use": "mobile",
      "value": "+1 (252) 5555 910 920 3"
    }
  ],
  "name": [
    {
      "use": "official",
      "family": "Chalmers",
      "given": [
        "Peter",
        "James"
      ]
    },
    {
      "use": "usual",
      "given": [
        "Jim"
      ]
    },
    {
      "use": "maiden",
      "family": "Windsor",
      "given": [
        "Peter",
        "James"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

… here is a possible query:

```
FOR client IN Patient
  FILTER LENGTH(client.telecom[* FILTER
    CONTAINS(CURRENT.value, "(03) 5555 6473") AND
    CURRENT.use == 'official']
  )
  RETURN {
    given: client.name[* FILTER CURRENT.use == 'official' RETURN CURRENT.given]
  }
```

Note that `client.telecom[*].value LIKE "..."` causes the array of phone numbers to be cast to a string `"[\"+1 (03) 5555 6473 82\",\"+1 (252) 5555 910 920 3\"]"` against which the LIKE operation is run - this kind of works, but it's not ideal.

`CONTAINS()` is also faster than `LIKE` with `%` wildcards on both sides.

It would be possible that there are multiple 'official' elements, which might require an extra level of array nesting. Above query produces:

```
[
  {
    "given": [
      [
        "Peter",
        "James"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

If you know that there is only one element or restrict it to one element explicitly then you can get rid of one of the wrapping square brackets with `FIRST()` or `FLATTEN()`.

Comment: hi CodeManX thanks for your assist. it's working properly.